# Read different lines in different files and write in one sentence

Tags: python

in f1 i have a file with these content

```
1000000000001
1000000000010
1000000000011 ...
```

in f2 same content but with different numbers
i want the result in f3 to be like this formated:

```
13'b1000000000001: y<= 6'b1000000000011;
13'b1000000000111: y<= 6'b1000000000010;
```

Code:

```
    f1 = open("/home//Downloads/Telegram Desktop/x_z.txt", "r")
f2 = open("/home//Downloads/Telegram Desktop/y_z.txt", "r")
f3 = open("/home//Downloads/Telegram Desktop/final.txt", "w")

lines1 = f1.readlines()
lines2 = f2.readlines()

for line1, line2 in zip(lines1, lines2):
    f3.write(f"13'b{line1}: y<= 6'b{line2};")
```

result:

```
13'b1000000000001
: y<= 6'b100111
```

Thank you for yuor time

Comment: you need to strip the data for new line character `f3.write(f"13'b{line1.strip()}: y<= 6'b{line2.strip()};")`

Answer (score 1):

`readlines()` keeps the newlines at the end of each line. This is what is causing you troubles.

One thing you could do is the explicit removal:

```
line1 = line1.strip('\n')
line2 = line2.strip('\n')
```

Then again, you can simplify the whole thing like this:

```
with open("/home//Downloads/Telegram Desktop/x_z.txt", "r") as f1,
    open("/home//Downloads/Telegram Desktop/y_z.txt", "r") as f2,
    open("/home//Downloads/Telegram Desktop/final.txt", "w") as f3:

    for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):
        f3.write("13'b{}: y<= 6'b{};\n".format(
            line1.strip('\n'), line1.strip('\n')))
```

Now you will even have the files `close`d for you at the end.

Comment: i get this error SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash

Comment: @realdobeja My fault, I did not even try it :/. There, I fixed it now by not using an f-string.

Comment: sorry again but in f3 file it should be like this :                                                                        13'b1000000000001: y<= 6'b1000000000011; newline
13'b1000000000111: y<= 6'b1000000000010;  newline ..

Comment: @realdobeja What is the problem with it now? I don't have your files to know what the output is. Maybe you want an additional newline after `;`? Is it just that?

Comment: in f3 it should have a new line after the concationation. So after ; newline. Yes

Comment: donee thank you very much with your help and for your time

Comment: Sure, I now added the newline to the answer.